# How to configure python+uwsgi+nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to run a python script with uwsgi+nginx.
It caused this error in the browser:

```
uWSGI Error
Python application not found
```

In `var/log/uwsgi/app/pyec.loc.log` the strings are:

```
Sun Mar  3 01:34:36 2013 - added /home/lunochkinma/py_projects/pyec/ to pythonpath.
Sun Mar  3 01:34:36 2013 - mounting hello on /home/lunochkinma/py_projects/pyec/
Sun Mar  3 01:34:36 2013 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Sun Mar  3 01:34:36 2013 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

My uwsgi app config:

```
<uwsgi>
        <plugin>python</plugin>
        <socket>/run/uwsgi/app/pyec.loc/pyec.loc.socket</socket>
        <pythonpath>/home/lunochkinma/py_projects/pyec</pythonpath>
        <app mountpoint="/">
                <script>hello</script>
        </app>
        <master/>
        <processes>4</processes>
        <harakiri>60</harakiri>
        <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
        <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
        <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
        <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
        <limit-as>512</limit-as>
        <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
        <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
        <no-orphans/>
        <vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

Python wsgi file:

```
# /home/lunochkinma/py_projects/pyec/hello.py

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return b'Hello World!'
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name paec.loc;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/pyec.loc.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/pyec.loc.error.log;
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/app/pyec.loc/pyec.loc.socket;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
                uwsgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;
        }
        location /static {
                root /home/lunochkinma/py_projects/pyec/static/;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

Soft: ubuntu 12.04, nginx 1.2.1, uwsgi 1.4.8, python 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> The problem is solved by adding to uwsgi app config parameter "module":
>
> ```
> <uwsgi>
>         <plugin>python</plugin>
>         <socket>/run/uwsgi/app/pyec.loc/pyec.loc.socket</socket>
>         <pythonpath>/home/lunochkinma/py_projects/pyec</pythonpath>
>         <app mountpoint="/">
>                 <script>hello</script>
>         </app>
>         <module>hello</module>
>         <master/>
>         <processes>4</processes>
>         <harakiri>60</harakiri>
>         <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
>         <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
>         <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
>         <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
>         <limit-as>512</limit-as>
>         <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
>         <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
>         <no-orphans/>
>         <vacuum/>
> </uwsgi>
> ```