# Set up python with nginx

Tags: python, configuration, nginx

I'm porting my web application from PHP to Python and I've decided for nginx as webserver. Now I'm trying to configure nginx to run Python (version 3) scripts with no framework.
Is it possible to configure nginx to run pure python scripts? If not, is any tutorial to use any python web framework only as backend, working with data, with no complicated configuration?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: You can use Python scripts with CGI. However that's a bad idea, as it's slow and full of gremlins and will be almost as bad and insecure as PHP. Use a framework. Really. It's much easier. The popular ones (in order of size) is Flask, Pyramid and Django.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179836/how-to-configure-pythonuwsginginx).